# How to get CONFIRMATIONTOKEN to delete attachment from VisualForce page?

Tags: attachment, delete

I'm trying to create a custom attachments list for the Account object via a visualforce page to replace the standard attachments related list Salesforce provides, which makes finding an attachment very difficult with all children attachments rolling up to the parent.

At this point, I have a custom visualforce page which lists only attachments associated with the account, ignoring all children attachments. I'm trying to reuse standard actions instead of having to recreate them in a controller. So, I have added the hyperlinks to View and Edit the attachment, but I'm having issues with the Delete attachment hyperlink, which is supposed to call the deleteredirect.jsp, but it needs a CONFIRMATIONTOKEN.

I tried to use URLFOR(), but it's not well documented and I'm not sure it works with Attachment. I've also searched through the Salesforce Apex documentation and through the web, but I couldn't find the correct answer. If I missed it for any reason, please feel free to point me to the right direction.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

SM

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem (mine was with Task Attachments) and in my research I came across this unanswered question. 
 Since I was able to solve it I thought I'd share what I found and hopefully save someone from all of the searching I had to do!  I was able to completely replicate the standard Attachment Actions using the following lines:

```
<apex:outputlink value="/{!att.id}/e?retURL=%2F{!task.id}" target="_parent">Edit</apex:outputlink>&nbsp;|&nbsp;

<apex:commandLink onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Delete,att.id,[retURL='/'+task.id], TRUE)}" target="_parent" Value="Del" />&nbsp;|&nbsp;

<apex:outputlink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,att.id)}" target="_blank">View</apex:outputlink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own method in apex controller of the page to delete attachment.

1. Createdelete as a command link and call a controller method and pass attachment ID as parameter
2. In the controller method delete attachment and rerender the list of attachments in page